# WP_User_Query pre user query DISTINCT Duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get unique results in this custom function:

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'rudr_extend_user_search');

function rudr_extend_user_search($u_query)
{
// make sure that this code will be applied only for user search
if ($u_query->query_vars['search']) {
    $search_query = trim($u_query->query_vars['search'], '*');
    if ($_REQUEST['search_name'] == $search_query) {
        global $wpdb;

        // let's search by users first name
        $u_query->query_from .= " JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} fname ON fname.user_id = {$wpdb->users}.ID AND fname.meta_key = 'first_name'";

        // you can add here any meta key you want to search by
        $u_query->query_from .= " JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} cstm ON cstm.user_id = {$wpdb->users}.ID AND cstm.meta_key = 'c_broker'";

        // let's search by all the post titles, the user has been published
        // $u_query->query_from .= " JOIN {$wpdb->posts} psts ON psts.post_author = {$wpdb->users}.ID";

        // what fields to include in the search
        $search_by = array('user_login', 'user_email', 'fname.meta_value', 'cstm.meta_value');

        // apply to the query
        $u_query->query_where = 'WHERE 1=1' . $u_query->get_search_sql($search_query, $search_by, 'both');
    }
}
}
```

I don't see where the `SELECT` code, so I don't know where to add `DISTINCT` to get unique results from the MySQL server.

Comment: Should probably use the `posts_distinct` hook for that.

Comment: I thought it would work with what you mentioned, but it did nothing :(